# Tracking javascript functions in console

Tags: javascript, console

how can i track down a function in the console? example: a function is set to display 30 seconds after page load, or on an element click event. or in the following example (live link below), how would i use the console to learn that my SayHi function is responsible for the console output "hi!"?:

```
function SayHi() {
    console.log("hi!");
}
var trigger = document.getElementById("hi_trigger");
trigger.onclick = function () {
    SayHi()
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hartogsmith/pmhsjf1a/

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there's no way to do this directly, but you could replace `console.log` with your own wrapper to insert a breakpoint inside it. When the breakpoint is hit you can inspect the call stack to see who is responsible for the call.

Example:

```
var originalConsoleLog = console.log;
console.log = function() {
    debugger; // will break into the debugger each time
    originalConsoleLog.apply(console, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
};
```

Comment: thanks, jon!  that works great in my example (where a function does some console.logging), but i'm trying to track some functions that are loaded by scripts i can't edit/control--trying to identify an externally loaded function that is causing a certain behavior.

Comment: @wagner: In that case any solution would probably be 100% from your browser development tools. But it's hard to say how and what without a concrete reproducible example.

Comment: thanks again, jon! jsfiddle cleans out or restricts a lot of external js, so creating an exact example was a challenge. i retooled my example and rephrase the question: if SayHi() was loaded from an external file that i can't edit (vs the local scripting in my example link), is there a way to have the chrome console report the name of SayHi or any other details?  similar to the way the console can report css per element. thanks! http://jsfiddle.net/hartogsmith/ynm4byj7/